# store data from excel in list after reading with java

Tags: java, arrays, apache-poi

i am using APACHE POI to read the data from excel files. I would like to store them in lists (like list in c) the result because afterwards I will try to store them in mysql database calling only list[0], list[1] for example. What i will try to do is make this list and after i will use jdbc driver and giving this list to make the tables in mysql.
The code for reading excel file is the above:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class readexcel{
```

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
//
 // An excel file name. You can create a file name with a full
 // path information.
 //
String filename = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\test.xls";

//
// Create an ArrayList to store the data read from excel sheet.
//
List sheetData = new ArrayList();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
//
// Create a FileInputStream that will be use to read the
// excel file.
//
fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

 //
 // Create an excel workbook from the file system.
//
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
//
// Get the first sheet on the workbook.
//
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

 //
  // When we have a sheet object in hand we can iterator on
// each sheet's rows and on each row's cells. We store the
// data read on an ArrayList so that we can printed the
// content of the excel to the console.
 //
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

List data = new ArrayList();
while (cells.hasNext()) {
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
data.add(cell);
 }

sheetData.add(data);
 }
 } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 } finally { 
 if (fis != null) {
 fis.close();
 }
 }

 showExcelData(sheetData);
  }

 private static void showExcelData(List sheetData) {
  //
    // Iterates the data and print it out to the console.
  //
for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
 List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
}
if (j < list.size() - 1) {
System.out.print(", ");
}
}
System.out.println("");
}
}
}
```

What i have to add to do what i explain you?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: could you explain your problem ? As far as i can see you already have your data in a List, so what step is your problem?

Comment: after reading the excel files i would like to store the data in mysql. The will give the name for the database but in this database each excel file will be a table. My purpose is when i create the table given the suitable command to take the values tha it has read before when it reads the excel file!

Comment: Firstly, do you understand what the code you've pasted above does? If you understand that, and what data is returns, you should be able to use the code below relatively easily.

Answer (score 1):

initialize the array list way before starting to iterate the sheet,
the array list must have a scope to persist anywhere in the row and column iteration of the excel sheet .

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList()
```

the put these line inside the cell iteration loop which is being performed n row basis

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
{
System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
myList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
} 
else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
{
System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
myList.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
} 
else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) 
{
System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
myList.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
}
```

now you process this list to insert data in to your DataBase

Answer (score 1):

I found this function usable

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> GetExcelTableInto2DArrayListString(String excelFile, boolean debug){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> OUT = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();  
        File myFile = new File(excelFile); 
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file 
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = null;
        try {
            myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook 
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0); 

        // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet 
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator(); 

        // Traversing over each row of XLSX file 
        int count=1;
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) { 
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            ArrayList<String> InnerArray = new ArrayList<String>() ;
            if(debug)System.out.print(count + ". \t");
        // For each row, iterate through each columns 
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); 

                switch (cell.getCellType()) { 
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
                    String c = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    if(debug)System.out.print(c + "\t");
                    InnerArray.add(c);
                    break; 
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: 
                    int n = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    if(debug)System.out.print(n + "\t");
                    InnerArray.add(String.valueOf(n));
                    break; 
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    boolean b = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    if(debug)System.out.print(b + "\t");
                    InnerArray.add(String.valueOf(b));
                break; 
                default : 
                    } 
                }
            if(debug)System.out.println("");
            OUT.add(InnerArray);
            count++; 
            }

    return OUT;
}
```

Comment: Please as your code is extend can you explain the main parts ?

Comment: I just needed something which will grab excel (xlsx) cells, row by row and as result place them into 2D String ArrayList. Works for me well.

Answer (score 0):

Look the code below

```
public List<ArrayList<String>> readExcelData2(String excelFile) throws IOException {

    List<ArrayList<String>> depts = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    FileInputStream excelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFile));

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFileToRead);

    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    XSSFRow row;
    XSSFCell cell;
    int maxDataCount = 0;

    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
        // skip the first row because it will be header
        if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
            maxDataCount = row.getLastCellNum();
            continue;
        }

        // if the row is empty stop the loop, do not go further
        if (this.isRowEmpty(row, maxDataCount)) {
            // exit processing
            break;
        }

        // define arraylist object to store list of departments of each row
        ArrayList<String> innerArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int cn = 0; cn < maxDataCount; cn++) {
            cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                innerArrayList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                innerArrayList.add(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                break;

            default:
                innerArrayList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            }

        }
        depts.add(innerArrayList);

    }
    return depts;
}

public boolean isRowEmpty(Row row, int lastCellNo) {
    for (int c = row.getFirstCellNum(); c < lastCellNo; c++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(c, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your conditions part to this should be work :

```
 if (cell.getCellType() == NUMERIC) {
    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    } else if (cell.getCellType() == STRING) {
    System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
    } else if (cell.getCellType() == BOOLEAN) {
    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    }
```